# Sync users between two forests - No trust relationship

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, active-directory, directoryservices

I am working on a project where I want to sync users from domain A to domain B (another forest). Both these domains (A&B) do not have trust relationship established. I have already developed sync service using `DirSync` control. My sync service will run on domain A.

I want to know what it the best and secure solution/channel to sync users to domain B like: SSL/TSL or any other option? Can anybody guide me how can I implement the same?

I am using C#.net and following namespaces: `System.DirectoryServices`, `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` and `system.directoryservices.accountmanagement`

Comment: Just connect to the other domain using valid credentials. If you already have a sync application then the rest should be easy.

Comment: Yeah but target is not a trusted domain. So I can't connect directly.

Comment: And sync application I am talking about is my custom app developed in C#. It is not FIM/MIM

Comment: Yes you can connect directly, you just need valid credentials from that domain. A trust is only required if you want a user in domain a to have permissions to something in domain b. If you connect from domain a using credentials for a admin user in domain b you dont need a trust.